# How can I see the results and how can the windows Close

Tags: vb.net

I have this code, and I´m calling one Java program to pass the aurguments, that I select in VB.

My issues is:

The cmd windows open, but I can't see what the program is doing, I only see on the window the arguments that are pass, and when finish, the window don't close.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWCWK.png)

and when program stop, the windows don't close.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpmTs.png)

This is the result if I run by command line

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pgkU.png)

```
        txbSendCommand.Text = "java -jar FACTEMICLI-2.5.16-33194-cmdClient.jar " & "-i " & TextBox1.Text & "" & " -n " & stNIF & " -p " & stPassword & " -a " & iAno & " -m " & iMes & " -op " & stvalidar & stFicheiroEscolhido & " -o c:\saft\outputfile.xml"

        Dim stcaminhoexterno As String
        If stErrorMessage = False Then

            Dim app As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe") With {.RedirectStandardInput = True, .UseShellExecute = False, .CreateNoWindow = False}
            Dim myProcess As New Process
            myProcess = Process.Start(app)
            Dim arguments As String = txbSendCommand.Text

            myProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(arguments)
            myProcess.Close()


        End If
```

How can I see the results in the external windows, or better even in a windows or something that I can have in the form.

How Can the window close after the process is done

Comment: Ignoring that you're closing the Process yourself just after you have started it, you should execute `java.exe` and set the `Arguments` property to what comes after. Do you need to read the results? If so, you have to redirect StdOut (i.e., set `RedirectStandardOutput = true`), better also StdErr, possibly subscribing to both the `OutputDataReceived` and `ErrorDataReceived` events, plus the `Exited` event, which can be used to dispose of the Process object -- Or simply redirect StdOut, read the stream to end and `WaitForExit()` (if you don't need to handle this asynchronously)

Comment: Don't forget to set the `WorkingDirectory`

Comment: Don't forget to read the `cmd /?` for the correct switch. One wonders why you are using `cmd.exe` in the first place.